# the meaning of 'Praying went out with the spears.'

Tags: sentence-meaning

> He refused to contribute to the synagogue building fund. "**Praying went
>   out with the spears**, Sam. You can quote me." A known supporter of the
>   communist causes, he was always good for a touch when there was a
>   strike or a defense fund or the *Tribune* was in trouble.
>
> -The Apprenticeship of Duddy Kravitz by Mordecai Richler -

What does the sentence mean?

Comment: It means he thinks prayer is primitive, outdated—like spears.

Comment: @ Robusto: oh.... got it.

Comment: An allusion to the Jewish-Roman wars?

Comment: @ Tᴚoɯɐuo: do you mind elaborating a little bit on this? I've read about the Jewish-Roman wars just now. Do you mean that once the Jews started the wars(spears), praying lost its meaning?

Comment: This is the speaker's way of saying that praying is irrelevant in the modern age, and it could also be understood to mean that revolution has supplanted prayer: revolution is relevant, prayer not.